# My CS50 Lab 8 Trivia Website's buttons aren't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, cs50

This is the html and javascript code for my website which has 2 questions :

- The first question has 4 buttons containing 4 options out of which there is only 1 correct answer
- The second question is text based free response answer

When I click on the buttons for the question 1 or the "Check answer" button for  question 2 nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated

```
<script>
// TODO: Add code to check answers to questions
//run the script once the DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentloaded', function(){

  //when correct answer is clicked change button colour to green
  let correct = document.querySelector('.correct');
  correct.addEventListner('click', function(){
    correct.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    document.querySelector('#feedback1').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
  });

  //When any incorrect answer is clicked, change color to red.
  let incorrects = document.querySelectorAll('.incorrect');
  for (let i=0; i < incorrects.length; i++){
    incorrects[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      incorrects[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      document.querySelector('#feedback1').innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
      });
    }

  //check free response submission
  document.querySelector('#check').addEventListner('click', function(){
    let input = document.querySelector('input');
    if (input.value === 'Switzerland'){
      input.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
    }else{
      input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
    }
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
            <hr>

            <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
            <h3>What is the approximate ratio of people to sheep in New zealand?</h3>
            <button class="incorrect">6 people per 1 sheep</button>
            <button class="incorrect">3 people per 1 sheep</button>
            <button class="incorrect">1 person per 1 sheep</button>
            <button class="incorrect">1 person per 3 sheep</button>
            <button class="correct">1 person per 6 sheep</button>

            <p id="feedback1"></p>

        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
            <hr>

            <!-- TODO: Add free response question here -->
            <h3>In which country is it illegal to own one guinea pig, as a lone guinea pig might be lonely?</h3>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button id="check">Check Answer</button>

            <p id="feedback2"></p>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct actually but there are two issues.

1. There is a spelling mistake with your `addEventListener` in 2 places, this is what you had -> `addEventListner`
2. You used
   `document.addEventListener('DOMContentloaded', function(){` instead
   of `window.addEventListener("load", function () {`. Please refer to other sources that goes into detail when you should be either one of these. ([Helpful source](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded))

The code that you have implemented is not the best javascript and HTML practices such as querying by input, not putting script at the end but if you are starting, not bad you did well. Also, you can use your browsers developers tools to debug and check your mistakes.

The following is the corrected and working version of the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
            <hr>

            <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
            <h3>What is the approximate ratio of people to sheep in New zealand?</h3>
            <button class="incorrect">6 people per 1 sheep</button>
            <button class="incorrect">3 people per 1 sheep</button>
            <button class="incorrect">1 person per 1 sheep</button>
            <button class="incorrect">1 person per 3 sheep</button>
            <button class="correct">1 person per 6 sheep</button>

            <p id="feedback1"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
            <hr>

            <!-- TODO: Add free response question here -->
            <h3>In which country is it illegal to own one guinea pig, as a lone guinea pig might be lonely?</h3>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button id="check">Check Answer</button>

            <p id="feedback2"></p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // TODO: Add code to check answers to questions
        //run the script once the DOM is loaded
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {

            //when correct answer is clicked change button colour to green
            let correct = document.querySelector('.correct');
            correct.addEventListener('click', function () {
                correct.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                document.querySelector('#feedback1').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
            });

            //When any incorrect answer is clicked, change color to red.
            let incorrects = document.querySelectorAll('.incorrect');
            for (let i = 0; i < incorrects.length; i++) {
                incorrects[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    incorrects[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    document.querySelector('#feedback1').innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
                });
            }

            //check free response submission
            document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', function () {
                let input = document.querySelector('input');
                if (input.value === 'Switzerland') {
                    input.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                    document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
                } else {
                    input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
                }
            }); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```